# Should I use Windows 8.1 SDK or Windows 10 SDK with Visual Studio 2017 for standard C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 to develop console applications in standard C++. When installing VS2017, I can install both Win 8.1 SDK and Win 10 SDK. VS2017 seems to offer Win 10 SDK by default, but I keep coming across projects that are configured to use Win 8.1 SDK (e.g., [MPIR](http://mpir.org) or projects created in previous versions of VS). Thus, I'm wondering:

- Which SDK is preferable to use for standard C and C++?
- Can I safely link together libraries that use different versions of Windows SDK? E.g., can I have MPIR compiled against Win 8.1 SDK and call it in an application that uses Win 10 SDK?

Comment: If you develop console applications in standard C++ you should not need or care about installed Windows SDK at all since you never use it.

Comment: @VTT This makes sense. Except that if I don't install 8.1 SDK, I cannot compile projects that refer to it in project settings. The compiler would complain about some headers missing. Is this a fake dependency (a compiler quirk that does not really matter)?

Comment: This is because Visual C++ is tightly bundled with Windows SDK. But as long as you don't use it directly you should not really care about version. You can actually install some third-party compiler and use it instead of Visual C++.

Answer (score -2):

This Microsoft [page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/4caf3bfc-2a57-48cb-b2a7-82e8c6185a65/what-version-of-the-sdk-should-i-use-in-vs2017) suggests that it usually doesn't matter which you use.  In particular, it says,

> When you deploy your application, you can link it with /MT option to completely avoid CRT related dynamic link libraries and in most cases you don't even need the redistributable run-time then. All the toolset functions are then present in your module and don't need any other dependencies.

Comment: The Windows SDK are not "CRT related dynamic link libraries".  You cannot statically link Windows OS functions (with a handful of exceptions such as the ones in `strsafe.h`).